# While hover on footer how to get underline and facebook icon color

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am learning automation with selenium-webdriver and trying to implement. So I am new to the topic. I have question for 2 Test Case
1. When I hover the mouse on Footer text it display underline. like go to https://www.yahoo.com/news/ and hover the mouse on Us or News Home it display underline. How do I check this one?
2. When I hover the house on Facebook icon it display different color while hover how do I check test one.
I wrote following code for my script. but it's not working
I few topic on stackoverflow but still not working.
public class UnderLine {

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  final String URL = "https://www.yahoo.com/news/";
  WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
  driver.manage().timeouts().setScriptTimeout(10000,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  driver.get(URL);

  WebElement news1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@title,'Politics')]"));  // For headline menu xpath
  WebElement followUs = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[4]/div[@class='Pos(r) D(ib) Cur(d) Va(t)' and 1]/div[@class='D(ib)' and 1]")); //Facebook xpath

  System.out.println("Before text decoration "+news1.getCssValue("border-bottom"));
  System.out.println(news1.getText());

  Actions nowHover = new Actions(driver);
  nowHover.moveToElement(news1).perform();
  Thread.sleep(10000);

  Actions nowHover1 = new Actions(driver);
  nowHover1.moveToElement(followUs).perform();
  Thread.sleep(10000);
  System.out.println(followUs.getCssValue("background-color"));
}
```

}

Comment: 1. you want to get the href of the element. 2. check the color property

Comment: @josh, I was checking getCssValue("color"); but not displayed different color. I have to check color property in both case?

Comment: In first case, you only need href since you want the link of the text.  In second case, you want to check color of the f icon, using the 'color' property instead of background-color.  It will change from color: rgb(0, 0, 0);  to      color: rgb(59, 89, 152);

Comment: @Josh For FB color I am running in chrome and I am getting following result 
FB Before Colorrgba(0, 0, 0, 1)
FB After Colorrgba(0, 0, 0, 1). For 1st one I want to check while hover the mouse it display blue underline. So how do I check with href?

Comment: @JoshAdams here is an example what I am looking for Go to https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/headless-execution-selenium-tests-jenkins Hover the mouse on Load Testing or any option and you will see blue color underline. That's what I am looking for.